# Exporting raster data to a spatial grid in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster as follows:

```
library(geostatsp)
library(raster)
library(sp)

xmin <- -11.69
xmax <- 2988.31
ymin <- -749.97
ymax <- 1650.03
res_r <- 50
r <- squareRaster(extent(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), cells=xmax*ymax)
res(r) <- res_r
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
print(r)

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 48, 60, 2880  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 50, 50  (x, y)
extent     : -11.69, 2988.31, -749.9699, 1650.03  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0.0005739587, 0.9996859  (min, max)
```

Using the raster, I can obtain the cell center coordinates as follows:

```
coord_r <- rasterToPoints(r, spatial=TRUE)
map_pts <- data.frame(x=coordinates(coord_r)[,1], y=coordinates(coord_r)[,2], coord_r@data)
```

However, I would like to obtain the coordinates of cell vertices (or four corner coordinates of each grid cell) instead of cell center coordinates. To do this, I've created a spatial grid by offset, cell size and dimensions as follows:

```
r_g <- GridTopology(c(xmin,ymin), c(res_r, res_r), c(ncol(r) + 1, nrow(r) + 1))
```

The grid `r_g` should contain 2989 observations.

But I don't know how to export raster data to the grid `r_g`.

Here are some details about how I obtain a grid with 2989 observations:

```
## 1) I retrieve cell vertices
polyg <- rasterToPolygons(r)
polyg@data$ID_poly <- rownames(polyg@data)
colnames(polyg@data) <- c("variable", "ID_poly")
polyg_vertices <- spbabel::sptable(polyg)
polyg_vertices <- polyg_vertices[!(polyg_vertices$order_==5), c("object_", "order_", "x_", "y_")]
colnames(polyg_vertices) <- c("ID_poly", "order", "x", "y")
tab_polyg_vertices <- join(polyg_vertices, polyg@data, by="ID_poly")

## 2) I delete duplicated values
tab_polyg_vertices <- tab_polyg_vertices[,c("x","y")]
tab_polyg_vertices <- unique(tab_polyg_vertices)
dim(tab_polyg_vertices)
[1] 2989    2
```

However, I don't know how to retrieve raster data (here, the values of the column "variable") because there are several values for the same corner coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in coercion methods for raster to sp classes, track rownames and the merge everything to a point feature class representing the "vertices" with duplicates removed. No idea as to why you want to ever to return an arbitrary subset of corner points representing raster cells but, here it goes.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

r <- raster(xmn=-11.69, xmx=2988.31, ymn=-749.97, ymx=1650.03,
            resolution=c(50,50))
  r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
```

Coerce straight to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and then pull x,y coordinates for corners of each cell. You will notice that since these are polygons there are 5 coordinate pairs with the last one being a duplicate of the first to provide closure. The for loop collapases the list into a single level and replaces the coordinate matrix, for each cell, with a data.frame that includes the associate rowname from the source grid.

```
r.sp <- as(r, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")

xy <- lapply(slot(r.sp, "polygons"), function(x) lapply(slot(x,"Polygons"), 
             function(y) slot(y, "coords")))             
  for(i in 1:length(xy)){
    xy[[i]] <- data.frame(GID=row.names(r.sp)[i], xy[[c(i,1)]])
  }
```

We can now create a dataframe with all of the coordinate pairs and row ids from the source grid, remove duplicates and coerce to a SpatialPointsDataFrame. It is important to acknowledge that by removing duplicates an arbitrary subset of corner coordinates, along with associated attributes, is being created.

```
xy <- do.call(rbind, xy)
  names(xy) <- c("GID","X","Y") 
  xy <- xy[!duplicated(xy[,2:3]),]
    coordinates(xy) <- ~X+Y
```

Now, finally we merge the SpatialPointsDataFrame with the @data slot from the original grid.

```
xy <- merge(xy, r.sp@data, by.x="GID", by.y="row.names", all.x=TRUE)
  head(xy@data)
  dim(xy)
```

Plot points on top of grid. Note, if you resize the plot canvas you need to re-plot everything otherwise things will not align.

```
plot(r)
  plot(r.sp, add=TRUE)
    points(xy, pch=20, cex=0.75, col="red")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The grid should contain 2989 observations (or cell vertices) instead of 2880 observations .

Comment: Sorry but, a bit nit picky. Your question was on coercing the data. I have no idea what you mean by "cell vertices" and I have been a spatial statistician for over 20 years. From a raster you either get the cell centroids or, if a SpatialGridDataFrame object you could plausibly, get the four corner coordinates of each grid cell. Given certain software the cell coordinates represent the lower left of the cell and not the center. I do not understand what would account for a 109 count difference with "vertices" vs. cell coordinates. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry, "cell vertices" correspond to the four corner coordinates of each grid cell.

Comment: Then with 2880 cells should you not have 11,520 "vertices"? After all there are 4 corners for each cell. Even if you just wa Ted the opposing corner coordinates it would still be 5,760. How are you comming up with 2989? Perhapse if you stated your final goal we may be able to provide some relevant guidance here as well. I can't imagine to what end you need attributed corner coordinates for a raster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You're right. I've added some details about how I obtain a grid with 2989 observations.